# iOS MapKit - Creating a line between two points by keeping in view the spherical trajectory of Earth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mapkit

http://i40.tinypic.com/33uesl2.png

Hi, I need something like the above (please check link) to do in iOS MapKit. The above screeshot is from google maps. I am currently drawing line between the two points but it is in a straight line. I need some code that can account for the trajectory of the earth.

The point B can change to any location in world. I need a way to create the line which can account for the trajectory.

Thanks.

Comment: This is called a geodesic line.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code this will create a route between two points
https://github.com/route-me/route-me

Comment: Thanks, I have already checked it. I want to create the line as a bird fly route rather than driving routes or walking routes. I have checked many examples from github and other sources but couldn't find any solution to meet my needs. Thanks anyways for the effort.